# What's the difference between classifier and downstream and only using classifier

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I'm new to Java 8 and streams Collectors trying to understand what's the basic difference between the two?

Because both the code yeild the same results. One uses `return groupingBy(classifier, toList());` and return groupingBy(classifier, HashMap::new, downstream);

Here is the code

```
public class Grouping {
    enum CaloricLevel { DIET, NORMAL, FAT };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Dishes grouped by type: " + groupDishesByType());
        System.out.println("Dish names grouped by type: " + groupDishNamesByType());
    }


    private static Map<Type, List<Dish>> groupDishesByType() {
        return Dish.menu.stream().collect(groupingBy(Dish::getType));
    }

    private static Map<Type, List<String>> groupDishNamesByType() {
        return Dish.menu.stream().collect(groupingBy(Dish::getType, mapping(Dish::getName, toList())));
    }
}
```

output:

```
Dishes grouped by type: {MEAT=[pork, beef, chicken], OTHER=[french fries, rice, season fruit, pizza], FISH=[prawns, salmon]}
Dish names grouped by type: {MEAT=[pork, beef, chicken], OTHER=[french fries, rice, season fruit, pizza], FISH=[prawns, salmon]}
```

**Dish.java**

```
public class Dish {

    private final String name;
    private final boolean vegetarian;
    private final int calories;
    private final Type type;

    public Dish(String name, boolean vegetarian, int calories, Type type) {
        this.name = name;
        this.vegetarian = vegetarian;
        this.calories = calories;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public boolean isVegetarian() {
        return vegetarian;
    }

    public int getCalories() {
        return calories;
    }

    public Type getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public enum Type {
        MEAT, FISH, OTHER
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    public static final List<Dish> menu = asList(
            new Dish("pork", false, 800, Dish.Type.MEAT),
            new Dish("beef", false, 700, Dish.Type.MEAT), 
            new Dish("chicken", false, 400, Dish.Type.MEAT),
            new Dish("french fries", true, 530, Dish.Type.OTHER), 
            new Dish("rice", true, 350, Dish.Type.OTHER),
            new Dish("season fruit", true, 120, Dish.Type.OTHER), 
            new Dish("pizza", true, 550, Dish.Type.OTHER),
            new Dish("prawns", false, 400, Dish.Type.FISH), 
            new Dish("salmon", false, 450, Dish.Type.FISH));

    public static final Map<String, List<String>> dishTags = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        dishTags.put("pork", asList("greasy", "salty"));
        dishTags.put("beef", asList("salty", "roasted"));
        dishTags.put("chicken", asList("fried", "crisp"));
        dishTags.put("french fries", asList("greasy", "fried"));
        dishTags.put("rice", asList("light", "natural"));
        dishTags.put("season fruit", asList("fresh", "natural"));
        dishTags.put("pizza", asList("tasty", "salty"));
        dishTags.put("prawns", asList("tasty", "roasted"));
        dishTags.put("salmon", asList("delicious", "fresh"));
    }
}
```

Comment: your examples in code are different than the examples in question... `Collectors.mapping` vs `groupingBy(classifier, HashMap::new, downstream)`. what is your actual question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your two examples

```
.collect(groupingBy(Dish::getType));
.collect(groupingBy(Dish::getType, mapping(Dish::getName, toList())));
```

return value the same because your `toString()` method in `Dish` class return `name` only. Try to add more info to `toString()` mehtod and you will see difference.

In general, using `groupingBy` with only classifier allows to group objects, like in your first example. But using `goupingBy` with classifier and downstream allows you to group much more than your objects only. For example you can group **average calories by type**:

```
.collect(groupingBy(Dish::getType, averagingInt(Dish::getCalories));  // Map<Type, Double>
```

Or find the **most caloric dish each type**:

```
.collect(groupingBy(Dish::getType, maxBy(Comparator.comparingInt(Dish::getCalories)));  // Map<Type, Optional<Dish>>
```

Often `groupingBy` is used as a downstream itself for double grouping (by type and by if it's vegeterian):

```
.collect(groupingBy(Dish::getType, groupingBy(Dish::isVegetarian)); // Map<Type, Map<Boolean, List<Dish>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is the question

> Because both the code yeild the same results. One uses return groupingBy(classifier, toList()); and return groupingBy(classifier, HashMap::new, downstream); ?

**groupingBy(Function classifier,Collector downstream)**

> There are no guarantees on the type, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety of the Map returned.

**groupingBy(Function classifier, Supplier mapFactory,
Collector downstream)**

> The Map produced by the Collector is created with the supplied factory function.

The only difference is when you use `groupingBy` with `mapFactory` the `Map` created is based on your supplier logic (might be custom, immutable, synchronized etc..)

Answer (score 0):

> what's the basic difference between the two?

The primary difference is the ***mapping*** that you've done in the intermediate step before *finishing* the collector. The way you've used them differently though is the signature of the `groupingBy`.

While *on one hand*, you've specified the `mapper` and `downstream` collectively as:

```
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Dish::getType,  // classifier
             Collectors.mapping(Dish::getName,  // mapper <<<< difference here
                 Collectors.toList()))) // downstream
```

*On the other,* the [deault implementation of `groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function)) is used in

```
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Dish::getType))
```

which can be expanded to some format similar as :

```
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Dish::getType, // classifier
             Collectors.mapping(Function.identity(),  // mapper
                 Collectors.toList()))); // downstream
```